Connect Walle Modal shows 2 Metamask options while using RainBowKit
I was trying to integrate Metamask and Phantom wallet into my presale website.
But when I click the "connect wallet" button, it shows 2 metamask (and/or phantom) wallet.
I have installed only 1 extension.
This error only happens the first time you open the browser.
2 Wallet appears on Modal
